# Sort a dictionary in decreasing order and in increasing order when there is a same number

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I need to sort a dictionary in python in decreasing order, but when the dictionary has two times a number I need to sort those numbers in increasing order:

Example:

Dictionary:

```
t = {0: 8, 1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 0, 4: 3, 5: 6, 6: 8, 7: 8, 8: 1, 9: 3}
```

My code:

```
dict(sorted(t.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda item: item[1]))
```

Output:

```
{0: 8, 6: 8, 7: 8, 5: 6, 1: 4, 2: 4, 4: 3, 9: 3, 8: 1, 3: 0}
                         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Output needed:

```
{0: 8, 6: 8, 7: 8, 5: 6, 2: 4, 1: 4, 4: 3, 9: 3, 8: 1, 3: 0}
                         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

How can I do that with the `lambda` function?

Thanks in advance for any response

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want to sort the dictionary by value in decreasing order but for same value sort keys in increasing order. Is that right?

Comment: You expected output contradicts your requirement.  When the values are equal, the output needed actually has the keys in **decreasing** order.

Comment: @trincot, That is why I asked. For value 8, increasing key order. For value 4, decreasing key order.

Comment: _when the dictionary has two times a number_ Do you mean **exactly** two, or **at least** two?

Comment: Ah, yes, @Abdur, didn't spot that. Asker must clarify this inconsistency.

Comment: Also, for this kind of operation, personally, I prefer to use elaborate function instead of lambda. Makes it easier to write, scale and debug.

Comment: The numbers can be two or more

Comment: Yes, I want to sort the dictionary by decreasing order and for the same value in increasing order

Comment: decreasing order and increasing order of what? keys? values? That is what you need to clarify.

Comment: I know the question is contradictory but I need to do this

Comment: @Pietroos 8 and 3 are repeated values too, why aren't those following the same logic as 4?

Comment: @AbdurRakib I thought that was obvius, I need to sort by value.

Comment: If you want it exactly the same way you wrote in your question (i.e., you made no typing mistake), that is not possible, I think. And no, your question is still not clear enough. I get that you want to sort by values and I assume in decreasing order. Then what is it about increasing order. And a bold assumption from me, maybe you need to look up what is key and what is value in dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For getting the keys in decreasing order when the value is the same, just add the key in the lambda function:

```
key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0])
```

As this really reverses the order of `item`, you can also do:

```
key=lambda item: item[::-1]
```